# Using an String Array for a JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have to have a drop down list of all the current accounts in this Account Manager project I have been working on. I have been trying to use this JComboBox and it works just fine with hard coded an array of strings but when I read in from a file and put it into an array it won't work. I already tested to see if there was anything in the array and there is.

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("data");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

String line;
int num_lines = 0;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
num_lines++;
}

String [] accountData = new String[num_lines];

for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
{
accountData[i] = reader.readLine();
}


JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(accountData);
```

Comment: So you read all the lines to get a count of how many lines there are, and then you keep reading to get the actual data? Does that make any sense to you? It certainly doesn't to me!

Comment: But then I am assigning it to array accountData and using that in my JComboBox, at least I think that's what I'm doing?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to Java, I have been using the Window builder and then going in to write the extra code. But I have a txt file I'm reading in.

Comment: You have to reset the reader before you can read it again, currently it's at the EOF before the second loop is executed.  Better to use a `List` of some kind

Comment: What are you assigning to `accountData`? `reader.readLine()` returned `null`, so it doesn;t have any data for you - what was there you have already seen and thrown away.

Answer (score -1):

try this mate:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("data");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
String line;
int num_lines = 0;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
  num_lines++;
}

String [] accountData = new String[num_lines];

for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++){
  accountData[i] = reader.readLine();
  comboBox.addItem(accountData[i]);
}
```